Is there a reason why the Nobel Prize in physics 2024 is awarded to a computer scientist instead of a physicist?
Is there a reason why the Nobel Prize in physics 2024 is awarded to a computer scientist instead of a physicist?
This is  an  insult to the people who are working on the real physics. A Nobel Prize in Physics should be awarded to scientists carrying out real physics research, encouraging those who work hard on fundamental research.

I kinda figured the Nobel Committee announced their reasoning, instead of just throwing a name out there. Did you read it?

What according to you is "real physics" and who gets to decide that?

It seems like the other "real physicists" want to capture and claim this sort of work as part of physics rather than having only a very narrow view of what it means to be "physics".

@quantacad Machine Learning and AI have nothing to do with physics

Such things can be a tool to unlock the answers to difficult questions that are asked by physicists, especially when a lot of data seems to obscure the answers rather than reveal them. "..nothing to do with physics" is far too strong.

Sidecomment: besides what Buffy correctly said, there are also people using statistical physics tools to understand why and how neural networks acutally work/generalize properly... and all that.

@BryanKrause an obligatory xkcd https://xkcd.com/435/

Probably a way better fit for the Physics stack.

I quote the concluding remarks in the report on why they were given the Nobel Prize in Physics:

With their breakthroughs, that stand on the foundations of physical science, they have showed a completely new way for us to use computers to aid and to guide us to tackle many of the challenges our society face. Simply put, thanks to their work Humanity now has a new item in its toolbox, which we can choose to use for good purposes. Machine learning based on ANNs is currently revolutionizing science, engineering and daily life. The field is already on its way to enable breakthroughs toward building a sustainable society, e.g. by helping to identify new functional materials. How deep learning by ANNs will be used in the future depends on how we humans choose to use these incredibly potent tools, already present in many aspects of our lives.


A small side comment who also uses the results from their work: on a personal level, I also think it is rather unconventional to be called within Physics. But only that, not wrong or inappropriate. Perhaps no other Physics discovery really climbed the mark?! Who knows...

That logic makes about as much sense to as awarding a Nobel prize in physics to the first person to use differential equations to study economics.

The Nobel Prize website explains why the Nobel committee considers the work to count as physics.
It seems from reading this that they regard the discovery as one primarily of information theory, very much in the mold of Shannon. They also talk a lot about the connections with statistical physics and the Boltzmann distribution.
It's worth noting that the Nobel committees have long had a fairly broad interpretation of the disciplinary boundaries. For example a case could be made for 7 of the last 10 laureates in chemistry actually being in (non-medical) biology, rather than chemistry.

If you look at Wikipedia's article on the Nobel Prize in Chemistry, there is a section on the "Scope of the Award".

In recent years, the Nobel Prize in Chemistry has drawn criticism from chemists who feel that the prize is more frequently awarded to non-chemists than to chemists. In the 30 years leading up to 2012, the Nobel Prize in Chemistry was awarded ten times for work classified as biochemistry or molecular biology, and once to a materials scientist. In the ten years leading up to 2012, only four prizes were awarded for work strictly in chemistry. Commenting on the scope of the award, The Economist explained that the Royal Swedish Academy of Sciences is bound by Nobel's bequest, which specifies awards only in physics, chemistry, literature, medicine, and peace. Biology was in its infancy in Nobel's day and no award was established. The Economist argued there is no Nobel Prize for mathematics either, another major discipline, and added that Nobel's stipulation of no more than three winners is not readily applicable to modern physics, where progress is typically made through huge collaborations rather than by individuals alone.

As you can see, some chemists are annoyed too that the Nobel Prize in Chemistry appears to be going to non-chemists quite often. The reason appears to be:

Nobel's will was applicable to the science of his day, but not modern science, where progress is not made by individual scientists.
Nobel specified only three science disciplines. For whatever reason, Nobel didn't establish a prize for biology & mathematics (and computer science), which of course doesn't mean those disciplines are insignificant.
(Reading between the lines) It seems the Nobel committee feel that they should be honoring progress in all science, not just the three that Nobel specified. This is why they honored biochemists & material scientists. Since deep learning represents a genuine breakthrough, they decided to award a prize for it, even though it's not really physics.

You could argue of course that the Nobel Prize in Physics should be awarded to physics only, blame Nobel for there being no computer science award, too bad for computer scientists who already have the Turing award anyway, etc. etc. If enough people agree with you, that might get the Nobel committee to change their policies.
PS: For this case at least, the motivation was from physics, and it was invented to understand certain phases of matter
